# Remove the language bar (and/or English language from it)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I have my Windows in English, but I don't use the English keyboard. I removed English from the lanuage list, in order do not accidentally switch (Shift+Tab) the keyboard.

I don't want at all the language bar to be active, to appear, to be visible, to exist. I want only use my french keyboard.

WHERE FROM THIS "ENG" LANGUAGE APPEAR AND HOW TO REMOVE IT?

[image]

also that is incredible
[image]

the bar as you can see from the first picture, is visible.

I suppose it should be related to the fact that my little child pressed some keys and opened Windows Magnifier, from there I saw the language bar appear, and now I can't hide it anymore.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot ?